# Need new way to add a UITextField to a UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So my app was rejected (it has been approved every other time i have put it in for review and I hadn't touched this code path in ages) or this line:

```
[myAlert addTextFieldWithValue:nil label:NSLocalizedString(@"Name",@"Name")];
```

Apparently `addTextFieldWithValue:label:`
is a private API...
so how are we supposed to put a UITextField inside an AlertView?

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. Alert views are for displaying alerts only. Apple uses them to display text fields sometimes, but that's their prerogative (since they wrote the HI guidelines and all).

Find a different approach in your UI for prompting the user for data. This is a mobile platform, not a desktop. Using popups like this for information gathering on such a platform is *usually* inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a [modal view controller](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1), instead. No risk of app rejection.