# iOS / UITextField in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertview

When the user presses my 'import' button, they must be able to type in a URL, which they can then 'ok' or 'cancel'.

How do I do this?

Obviously I could create a new view containing a text field and 2 buttons.   But this seems like over coding.

One solution I found involves ' hacking ' a UITextField into a UIAlertView: http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2009/12/username-and-password-uitextfields-in.html

(EDIT: Better -- http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1704-uitextfield-inside-uialertview.html#post10643 )

This looks really ugly.  It is clearly a hack.

Can anyone provide a better solution (or even a better implementation of the same solution path)?

Comment: Erm.. why don't you use `textfield.text`or am I not understanding you right?

Comment: Sorry,  my bad wording. I have edited the question.

Comment: Also discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376104/uitextfield-in-uialertview-on-iphone-how-to-make-it-responsive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK After a ton of digging, here is the result.

Firstly,  putting in 'UITextField UIAlertView' into SO's search returns dozens of hits.

It turns out there is a method for doing this, [Need new way to add a UITextField to a UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767680/need-new-way-to-add-a-uitextfield-to-a-uialertview)  but it is private API :|

Pretty much every other solution involves hacking a UIAlertView, which is ugly:
http://junecloud.com/journal/code/displaying-a-password-or-text-entry-prompt-on-the-iphone.html
http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2009/12/username-and-password-uitextfields-in.html
https://github.com/josecastillo/EGOTextFieldAlertView/
[How to move the buttons in a UIAlertView to make room for an inserted UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409599/how-to-move-the-buttons-in-a-uialertview-to-make-room-for-an-inserted-uitextfield)
^ MrGando's answer is neat
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/alert-view-with-prompt.html
[Getting text from UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560346/getting-text-from-uialertview)

The only proper solution I found (ie coding from scratch from a UIView) is here: https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView

This is all it takes:

```
- (IBAction) importTap
{
    TSAlertView* av = [[[TSAlertView alloc] init] autorelease];
    av.title = @"Enter URL";
    av.message = @"";

    [av addButtonWithTitle: @"Ok"];
    [av addButtonWithTitle: @"Cancel"];


    av.style = TSAlertViewStyleInput;
    av.buttonLayout = TSAlertViewButtonLayoutNormal;
    av.delegate = self;

    av.inputTextField.text = @"http://";

    [av show];
}

// after animation
- (void) alertView: (TSAlertView *) alertView 
didDismissWithButtonIndex: (NSInteger) buttonIndex
{
    // cancel
    if( buttonIndex == 1 )
        return;

    LOG( @"Got: %@", alertView.inputTextField.text );
}
```

and Presto!

[image]

Comment: Actually, text fields in `UIAlertView`s will be supported in iOS 5. That's the only caveat though, iOS 5.

Comment: re:Actually, text fields in UIAlertViews will be supported in iOS 5.        http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-sdk-uialertview-text-input-and-validation/

Answer (score 0):

Check out: https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextFieldAlertView

Answer (score 0):

I have created a post in my blog on the topic "How to add UITextField to UIAlertView from XIB". Using XIB to add is easier than pure coding. You can add whatever in a customized small view, then add the small view into the AlertView using 1 line code. Please refer to the following link.

http://creiapp.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-add-uitextfield-to-uialertview.html