# support for uialertview with text field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uialertview

Does anyone know whats the solution for pre iOS5 if I want to show a pop UIAlertView with a text field? A solution that would be acceptable by Apple?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS / UITextField in UIAlertView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735968/ios-uitextfield-in-uialertview)

Comment: i saw that - doesn't really answer my question, but thanks.

Comment: I don't think you read it then... There are several excellent tutorial links (from 2009, back when iOS 3.2 was released).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, I have a pre-iOS5 app in the App Store with such a text field.

Just add the text view as a `subview` to the alert view and figure out the spacing by inserting an appropriate amount of `\n` into the `message` to make room for the field.

Comment: thanks! is there anywhere online that you can point me where it says that its ok?

Comment: Right here. **I** am telling you online. My app is live and earning good money. Apple is using the same scheme for when you input your password for the app store. There can be no discussion that this is not braking any HIG guidelines.

Comment: well, apple can do whatever they want..:) whats your app if I may ask?

Comment: SalesCallPlanner. I am pulling it soon to be replaced by Sales Plus and Sales Star.